# How to animate more than two points on a trapezoid?

Tags: animation, swiftui

Part of the UI that I'm working on has large elements changing size in response to user input.  Animating the views changing size is straightforward; what I'm working on now is building trapezoids that provide a visual transition between similarly colored rectangles (Views) of different sizes, and I want the length of the trapezoids' tops & bottoms to change size smoothly as the rectangles above & below change size.

So far, I have the following code which can animate the two bottom points changing in response to user input, and it works fine.  What I need to do is extend this so that not just TWO x-coordinates can change with animation, but all FOUR x-coordinates.  (The y-coordinates don't vary, so all that is being passed that needs to animate are the x values.)

```
struct NewTrapezoid: Shape {
  var xTopLeft : Double
  var xTopRight : Double
  var xBottomLeft : Double
  var xBottomRight : Double
  var height : Double
  var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Double, Double> {
    // top two points WERE always fixed  -- the base of the top rectangle
    // what needs to happen NEXT is that these two top points can animate. Present code, they don't.
    // the y-coord of the bottom two points are fixed -- height of the transition zone
    // these two doubles are the X coords of the two bottom points. They animate fine.
    get { AnimatablePair(xBottomLeft, xBottomRight) }
    set {
      xBottomLeft = newValue.first
      xBottomRight = newValue.second
      }
    }
  }

  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let topLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: xTopLeft, y: 0)
    let bottomLeft: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: xBottomLeft, y: height)
    let topRight: CGPoint  = CGPoint(x: xTopRight, y: 0)
    let bottomRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: xBottomRight, y: height)
    var path = Path()
    path.move(to: topLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
    path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
    path.addLine(to: topLeft)
    return path   
  }
}
```

What I suspect would make things easy is if, instead of `AnimatablePair<Double, Double>` I could have something like `AnimatableMany<Double, Double, Double, Double>` but I haven't found a way to do that.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values, you can cascade/nest AnimatablePairs like this:

```
AnimatablePair< Double, AnimatablePair< Double, AnimatablePair< Double, Double>>>
```

But as you can see, this is not very flexible and usable for more than 4 or 5 values

A better solution is to create a custom type that conforms to VectorArithmetics, like this [AnimatableVector](https://gist.github.com/izakpavel/5d581041464e40b9fd29440bbfed6708)